# Como saber se a pessoa é maior de idade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Estou precisando de ajuda pra criar um código Javascript ou usando jQuery, que deve ler o valor da data de nascimento da pessoa(estou usando o datepicker) e calcular quantos anos que ela tem.
Eu tenho que mostrar em div falando se ela é de maior ou não, tenho  seguinte código:

```js
$("#entraridade").click(function () {
    var idade = 2016 - $("#date").val();
    $("#mostrar").text("Ola " + $("#name").val());
    $("#mostrar2").text("sua idade e :" + $("#idade").val());
});
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
    monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
    nextText: 'Proximo',
    prevText: 'Anterior'
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form">
    Nome:
    <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    Data de nascimento:         
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="data"/><br>
    <input type="button" id="entraridade" value="Ok">            
  </form>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
  <div id="resultado2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: primeiro vc define qual é a maioridade (no caso 18 anos), depois é só subtrair ano (atual - ano_nascimento) se o resultado for menor que a maioridade (18), ele é menor, senão maior.

Answer (score 4):

Usei uma função que retorna a diferença entre o ano atual menos o proposto o que retornará a *idade*.

*Veja funcionando:*

```js
function getIdade(data) {
   var hoje = new Date();
  
    var nascimento = new Date(convertDateMMDDYYY(data.split("/")));

    //Retorna a diferença entre hoje e a data de nascimento em anos.
    var ano = hoje.getFullYear() - nascimento.getFullYear();
 
    //Retorna a diferença de mês do mês de nascimento para o atual.
    var m = hoje.getMonth() - nascimento.getMonth();

    //Caso ainda não tenha ultrapassado o dia e o mês
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoje.getDate() < nascimento.getDate())) {
        ano--;
    }
    return ano;
}

function convertDateMMDDYYY(datearray) {
  return datearray[1] + '-' + datearray[0] + '-' + datearray[2];
}

function Is18() 
{
  var data = document.getElementById("datepicker");
   
  if(getIdade(data.value) >= 18)
       document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML= "Você tem 18 ou mais anos de idade!";
  else
     document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML="Você não tem 18 anos!";
}

$('#datepicker').datepicker();

   $.datepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
                closeText: 'Fechar',
                prevText: '&#x3c;Anterior',
                nextText: 'Pr&oacute;ximo&#x3e;',
                currentText: 'Hoje',
                monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Mar&ccedil;o','Abril','Maio','Junho',
                'Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun',
                'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda-feira','Ter&ccedil;a-feira','Quarta-feira','Quinta-feira','Sexta-feira','Sabado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
                weekHeader: 'Sm',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                firstDay: 0,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''};
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Nome:
    <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    
<p>Data de nascimento: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    <input type="button" id="entraridade" onclick='Is18()' value="Ok">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Na parte da :
var data = document.getElementById("datepicker");    Voce utilizou Javascript puro?

Comment: @user49003 sim, só a parte do datapicker que usei Jquery.

Comment: Me ajudou muito, obg.

Comment: Somente uma pequena duvida, tem como eu fazer somente em jQuery? Sou pouco experiente com jQuery estou començando agora.

Comment: Ha ta bom, qual é o erro nessa parte? porque eu tentei e não deu certo, olha:             
var data = $("datepicker").val();

                if ($("datepicker").val() >= 18)
                    alert("Você tem 18 ou mais anos de idade!");
                else
                    alert("Você não tem 18 anos!");

Comment: Tem que ser igual está no [comentario](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137503/como-saber-se-a-pessoa-%C3%A9-maior-de-idade/137518?noredirect=1#comment285098_137518).

Comment: Ha sim, muito obrigado ajudou bastante!

Comment: Marconi, eu não sei se é o snippet, mas aqui só considera como 18 anos se a data for menor que 1 de junho de 1998. Qualquer data maior que essa até o dia de hoje(29) é considerada como menor de 18.

Comment: @diegofm eu vi aqui, rs parece que essa data que você passou o new Date(data) não está conseguindo formatar de volta. Que estranho isso. ushaushausa

Comment: @diegofm valeu pela dica, realmente estava errado, corrigido :);

Comment: @user49003 Apenas uma recomendação a respeito da sua solicitação de se fazer apenas com jQuery, prefira sempre o Javascript puro (Vanilla) ao jQuery, que é nada mais que uma biblioteca do Javascript, pois sempre será mais rápido, use jQuery somente em casos essenciais e quando precisa-se manter compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos, do contrário dos haters do jQuery, não estou dizendo para não usar, mas usar quando precisar. :)

Comment: ha ta bom obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Só um detalhe eu precisava desse codigo somente em jQuery. :(