# Como pegar somente o valor do ano usando jquery e datapicker?

Tags: jquery, datapicker

Bom dia, estou fazendo um exercício que tenho que pegar somente o valor do ano que o usuário escolher usando Datepicker, e depois tenho que mostrar somente o ano que foi digitado.

Comment: Você pode tirar isso dessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137503/como-saber-se-a-pessoa-%C3%A9-maior-de-idade/137518#137518) que postei pra vc.

Comment: Desculpe mas não estou consegindo :(

Comment: Nessa parte `nascimento.getFullYear();` retorna o ano inserido no calendario.

Comment: Tem que ser somente em jQuery, eu não sei qual função no jQuery ou do UI pra fazer isto.

Comment: Quer que seja no submit do form ou no clique na data?

Comment: No clique na data, a pagina não pode atualizar então nao pode ser o submit nao.